# SVM OpenCV c++ Predict returning nothing but 1's

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm, image-recognition

I believe I have successfully trained an `SVM`, but when I try to predict with it, the output is entirely 1's.

My code for training looks like this:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < (testPosArraySize); i++){
    testGivenImg = imread(imagePosDir[i]);
    detector->detect(testGivenImg, testKeypointsPos);
    bowDE.compute(testGivenImg, testKeypointsPos, testFeaturesPos);
    testFeaturesPos.reshape(1, 1);
    testFeaturesVec.push_back(testFeaturesPos);
}
for(size_t i = 0; i < (testNegaArraySize); i++){
    testGivenImg = imread(image[i]);
    detector->detect(testGivenImg, testKeypointsNega);
    bowDE.compute(testGivenImg, testKeypointsNega, testFeaturesNega);
    testFeaturesNega.reshape(1, 1);
    testFeaturesVec.push_back(testFeaturesNega);
}

Mat labels(numSamples, 1, CV_32F);
labels.rowRange(0, testPosArraySize).setTo(1);
labels.rowRange(testPosArraySize + 1, numSamples).setTo(-1);
SVM.model.train(fileTestFeat, labels, Mat(), Mat(), SVMParams());
```

My code for prediction looks like this:

```
vector<Mat> predictMatVec(predictArraySize); // -- amount of testing images

for(size_t i = 0; i < (predictArraySize); i++){
    predictImg = imread(imageNegaDir[i]);
    detector->detect(predictImg, predictKeypoints);
    bowDE.compute(predictImg, predictKeypoints, predictFeatures);
    predictFeatures.reshape(1, 1);
    predictMatVec[i].push_back(predictFeatures);

    Mat predictMat = Mat(predictMatVec);
    float* predictFloat1D = (float*)predictMat.data;
    Mat predictMat1D(1, fileTestFeat.cols, CV_32FC1, predictFloat1D);
    float predictFloat = model.predict(predictMat1D);
    cout << " -- SVM output: " << predictFloat << endl; 
}
```

But it is returning nothing but 1's.

[image]

What is wrong with it?

Comment: What happens if you apply your model to the training database? Can you "separate" the training DB?

Comment: I don't see what information I would gain from that? And I don't follow your second question...

Comment: You are using the [`predict()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-predict) with the default `returnDFVal` so the function returns a class label (classification) or estimated function value (regression). I think your 1's are class labels, so all of your samples are classified as the element of the 1-label class. If you execute the prediction for the training database then I'd expect to see the other labels. If the prediction isn't working for the training DB then your training was wrong.

Comment: Set it up to run through the images used for training, simply stops working... And how do I make a 2 label class? I thought I had already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the vocabulary has been already created (e.g. by [`BOWKMeansTrainer`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html#bowkmeanstrainer)) and you start to train you SVM classifier, right?

At this point you have a feature detector, extractor, matcher and a BOW image descriptor extractor (to compute an image descriptor using the bag of visual words) such as:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SURF");
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF");
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher = cv::DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce ");

cv::BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowide(extractor, matcher);
bowide->setVocabulary(vocabulary);
```

First of all we need to scour the training set for our histograms:

```
cv::Mat samples;
cv::Mat labels(0, 1, CV_32FC1);

for(auto& it : imagePosDir)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(it);

    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector->detect(image, keypoints);

    if(keypoints.empty()) continue;

    // Responses to the vocabulary
    cv::Mat imgDescriptor;
    bowide.compute(image, keypoints, imgDescriptor);

    if(imgDescriptor.empty()) continue;

    if(samples.empty())
    {
        samples.create(0, imgDescriptor.cols, imgDescriptor.type());
    }

    // Copy class samples and labels
    std::cout << "Adding " << imgDescriptor.rows << " positive sample." << std::endl;
    samples.push_back(imgDescriptor);

    cv::Mat classLabels = cv::Mat::ones(imgDescriptor.rows, 1, CV_32FC1);
    labels.push_back(classLabels);
}
```

Do the same for `imagePosNeg` except that `classLabels` will have zero values, such as:

```
...
cv::Mat classLabels = cv::Mat::zeros(imgDescriptor.rows, 1, CV_32FC1);
labels.push_back(classLabels);
...
```

Note how I build the samples and the labels, I marked the positive samples with labels '1', and then the negatives with label '0'. So we have the training data for each class (here for positives and negatives) in `samples`. Lets's get training:

```
cv::Mat samples_32f; 
samples.convertTo(samples_32f, CV_32F);

CvSVM svm; 
svm.train(samples_32f, labels);
// Do something with the classifier, like saving it to file
```

Then testing let's get testing the classifier:

```
for(auto& it : testDir)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(it);

    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector->detect(image, keypoints);

    if(keypoints.empty()) continue;

    // Responses to the vocabulary
    cv::Mat imgDescriptor;
    bowide.compute(image, keypoints, imgDescriptor);

    if(imgDescriptor.empty()) continue;

    float res = svm.predict(imgDescriptor, true);

    std::cout << "- Result of prediction: " << res << std::endl;
}
```

Is it working?

---

**Update #1:**

Here I made a simple example about BOW+SVM under OpenCV 3.0:
https://github.com/bkornel/OpenCV_BOW_SVM/blob/master/main.cpp

This works me fine for classifying bottles of Coca Cola / Pepsi. I also published the binaries so you can have a try on your database. Hope it works :)

Comment: Looks to be? Output consists of either `-1` or `-0.9xxxxx` though, is that right? A few `0.8xxxxx` (`x` obviously being any single digit number) -- Changed the first 4 images to the first 4 images from the Positive Training Set, output is `-1` - `-0.993832` - `-0.981426` - `-1`

Comment: It is 2-class classification and `predict()` returns the decision function value that is a signed distance to the margin. If you want to know the labels then set the `returnDFVal` to `false`, i.e. `float res = svm.predict(imgDescriptor, false);`

Comment: The more you know! Well I changed it to `false` and the output was all ones again for about the first 20, but its slow going so I put in a `If` in so it will only write out if the `floats` that don't return `1's` (save sifting through all the ones)

Comment: It runs, but shouldn't there be a variation in output, ie not just `1's`? (As was my initial issue)

Comment: you should see zeros for the negatives and ones for the positives

Comment: I'll try and refine my training set and get back to you

Comment: With your update **(Best update ever btw)** you use the same set of images to create your vocabulary for the `BOWImgDescriptorExtractor` as you do to train the `SVM`. Are you supposed to do this? and also you create vocabulary with both `Positive` & `Negative` images?

Comment: That's right, during the training of classifiers (SVMs) it should be rather  used a different training set, because at this point check the features in the image for their closest clusters in the vocabulary.